# How to remove underline from a name on hover

Tags: html, css

I have such html:

```
<legend class="green-color"><a name="section1">Section</a></legend>

legend.green-color{
    color:green;
}
```

In my case `Section` looking green, but when i put mouse pointer on it it became looking like an a href, but i want it stay just the same without underline and changing color.

Is it possible to achieve without changing css or with minimum css change?

or may be somehow with jquery?

Answer (score 265, accepted):

try this:

```
legend.green-color a:hover{
    text-decoration: none;
}
```

Comment: FYI for people using Bootstrap...I needed to use "!important" after "none" for this to work. Example: a:hover{
    text-decoration: none !important;
}

Comment: Was also using Bootstrap and indeed adding "!important" made it work for me. To add, `text-decoration: none;` does not need to be in the :hover pseudo-class's styling. Adding the it in the a tag styling worked for both hovered and non-hovered states.

Answer (score 24):

Remove the text decoration for the anchor tag

```
<a name="Section 1" style="text-decoration : none">Section</a>
```

Comment: I don't mean to bring up a flame war here, but I like this in-line style. I mean my HTML file just need this type of style one or two times. I don't see the time justified by creating a separate style sheet even the separation makes a good practise.

Answer (score 7):

You can use CSS under `legend.green-color a:hover` to do it.

```
legend.green-color a:hover {
    color:green;
    text-decoration:none;
}
```

Answer (score 6):

To keep the color and prevent an underline on the link:

```
legend.green-color a{
    color:green;
    text-decoration: none;
}
```

Answer (score 4):

You can assign an id to the specific link and add CSS. See the steps below:

1.Add an id of your choice (must be a unique name; can only start with text, not a number):

```
<a href="/abc/xyz" id="smallLinkButton">def</a>
```

2. Then add the necessary CSS as follows:

   ```
   #smallLinkButton:hover,active,visited{

         text-decoration: none;
         }
   ```

Answer (score 3):

```css
legend.green-color{
    color:green !important;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

In `react` you need to do this

```
<Link to="/" style={{ textDecoration: 'none' }}>
....
</Link>
```

or if you are using `bootstrap` in `react` then use this class

```
className="text-decoration-none"
```